# Can't manipulate instantiated objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

Okay I'm new to c# , I m familiar with  WPF+VB.NET.
So I have a class Called 'Voiture'
if i try to instantiate an object of type 'Voiture' in MainWindow.cs,
I can do that but whenever I try to call that object to use one of its methods, the IDE ,simply has no reference of it ,even if it lets me instantiate it 
Am I missing something here ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication13
{
    class Test
    {
        Voiture b = new Voiture();
        b.speed();

    }
}
```

if i try    b.speed()   for example (speed is a method of the class            Voiture)   i get the error  :   Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Can you show where you are trying to use it?

Comment: It should probably be public: `public Voiture b = new Voiture();`. Now it is still a field. In order to use data binding, it would have to be a public property.

Comment: @Clemens Already tried that , no sucess

Comment: @BradleyDotNET   as written above in a simple class Test , even tried in the MainWindow class , same thing

Comment: `"the IDE ,simply has no reference of it"` - Well, the code shown in the question makes no attempt to reference the variable.  So I guess it's working as designed.  Maybe you can provide some information about the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @user3621917 *As written above* **nothing** tries to use the variable. Show us where it is failing, and we can help you

Comment: For example in my class 'Voiture' i have a  method called speed                            the IDE wont accept   b.speed();    it says cannot resolve symbol b

Comment: @user3621917: Again, and we can't stress this enough, the code in the question *makes no reference to the variable*.  So all we can assume is that you're trying to reference it outside of its available scope.  In which case the answer is to not do that.  We can't be any more specific without seeing *any* example of the problem.

Comment: I edited the code ,   i can't even write the line , the IDE does not recognize the variable

Comment: You must consider read some docs about c# syntax before coding. You can only declare variables, functions or contructors on the class scope.

Comment: I keep getting the error Cannot resolve symbol 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is structurally invalid:

```
class Test
{
    Voiture b = new Voiture();
    b.speed();
}
```

You can't imperatively invoke code outside the context of a method or function.  The first line, which declares the variable `b`, is fine because it's declaratively creating a class-level value.  But a *class* can't *execute* code statements.  Only a method or function can.  Something like this:

```
class Test
{
    Voiture b = new Voiture();

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        b.speed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication13
{
    class Test
    {
        Voiture b = new Voiture();
        b.speed(); // this is wrong

    }
}
```

this are the uses.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication13
{
    class Test
    {
        Voiture b = new Voiture();            

        public Test() // constructor
        { 
            b.speed();
         }

        public void function() // function
        { 
            b.speed();
        }
    }
}
```